# Can a New Member automatically become a Drupal User with defined Role?

Tags: drupal, civimember, drupal-rules

I would like to allow people who pay to become civicrm members to have access to protected DRUPAL pages. I would like it to happen right away rather than waiting for a batch operation.

My method is to make some DRUPAL RULES so that when a person becomes a member then they would automatically become a DRUPAL user with a specified ROLE. Then the pages would be open to that particular ROLE.

I found a way of creating a DRUPAL user if I add a TAG on a civicrm contact. So it seems like I just need a rule that adds the TAG when the contact becomes a member.

Here are my questions:

1)Does anybody know how to set up a rule to assign a tag to a new member?

2)Is there an easier way to accomplish my goal?

In gratitude,
Daniel

Answer (score 7):

Daniel - have you looked at the CiviMember Roles Sync module which pretty much delivers this as you want. IE when someone joins and has a Drupal user then when they log in Drupal checks their Civi Membership status and gives them a role based on that.

The Rules approach would also work, and is how we are planning on doing this for Drupal 8, funds permitting, but I don't think people have used that approach in D7 since the module gives you the solution out of the box, unless i am missing a nuance in your use case.

Some documentation about above [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMember+Roles+Sync)

Comment: CiviMember Role Sync Module is how we do it and we love it.

Comment: I don't understand the "workflow" correctly i guess. Does the user need to be a Drupal User already or is it sufficent to select a membership and then the user and the associated role will be created?

Comment: Actually we have just implemented a Rule so that a 'contact' who used a Contribution page, but might 'pay later' and hence should become a User till the payment is completed, will only get their User created once their membership becomes "new' as opposed to 'pending'.